# Are smarter merge conflict algorithms available for git?

Tags: git, algorithm, diff

When rebasing and Git generates merge conflicts they are sometimes pretty confusingly presented. For example if I have this code:

```js
async loadDirectory({ commit }, path: string) {
  ...
```

In `master` I make it `sync`:

```js
loadDirectory({ commit }, path: string): void {
  ...
```

And in `some_branch` (based off the original code) I add another function before it:

```js
async fetchData({ commit }) {
  lots();
  of();
  code();
},

async loadDirectory({ commit }, path: string) {
  ...
```

Now, if I try to rebase `some_branch` onto `master`, git shows this conflict:

```js
<<<<<<< HEAD
loadDirectory({ commit }, path: string): void {
=======
async fetchData({ commit }) {
  lots();
  of();
  code();
},

async loadDirectory({ commit }, path: string) {
>>>>>>> Add data fetching function
```

This is pretty confusing! It would be much easier to understand if it had presented the conflict like this:

```js
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
async fetchData({ commit }) {
  lots();
  of();
  code();
},
>>>>>>> Add data fetching function

<<<<<<< HEAD
loadDirectory({ commit }, path: string): void {
=======
async loadDirectory({ commit }, path: string) {
>>>>>>> Add data fetching function
```

I haven't actually looked into Git's algorithm but I suspect it optimises for algorithmic complexity, and a small number of conflict sections. But whatever the algorithm, this example shows that it could be improved (possibly for a performance cost).

My question is: is it theoretically possible to use a different algorithm with Git, and is anyone working on that?

Comment: Your problem come from that git use `patch` to apply the changes on a file and to do it, it needs a line of context at the beginning and the end of the lines modified (look at a patch file to understand well). These lines of context should not have changed to successfully apply the patch. And in your case, the line has been changed.

Comment: Your expected presentation of the conflict is wrong. Where does the empty line between the conflicts come from? It must be part of the first conflict. After you make that change, do you still think that your expected conflict presentation makes any sense?

Comment: @j6t: Yes I did that deliberately to make my intent a bit clearer. It doesn't change the question.

Comment: You clarified your intent, but are expecting Git to produce an incorrect result.

Comment: @j6t: Please stop nit-picking. The question is clear.

Comment: Set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3` and you'll get the merge base version included in the conflict section. I find this very helpful as it makes it easy to compare the middle (base) against the top (HEAD) and bottom versions.

Answer (score 7):

Git does not come with any fancier merge algorithms, but it *does* include a mechanism by which you can provide your own.  In fact, there are two mechanisms, but one is much more usable.

In particular, in your `.gitattributes` file, you can list a *merge driver* for particular file name patterns.  It's important to realize that this merge driver is *only* invoked in some particular cases.

At the top level, we invoke `git merge` using the command line, including these options.  There are more options, but these are the ones I want to call out in particular:

`git merge [-s strategy] [-X extended-options] commit-specifier`

The `-s` argument takes a *strategy*, and there are five built in strategies, but only one (or two or three depending on how you count) really matters:

- `recursive` and `resolve` are essentially the same one, except when there is more than one merge base (a case I won't discuss much here).  These are the ones that matter, and for the case we care about, they are pretty much identical.
- `octopus` is meant for use when specifying more than one *`commit-specifier`* argument; it builds an *octopus merge*, which is one with more than two parents.  I won't discuss this one either because octopus merges do not allow conflict resolution anyway.
- `ours` completely ignores all other commits and simply retains the current tree, so it's not suitable here.
- `subtree` is a kind of hacked-up variant of `recursive` for renaming subtrees, and hence really falls into the `recursive` category as well.

You *can* provide your own merge strategy!  All you have to do is write a command, name it `git-merge-whatever`, and run `git merge -s whatever` and Git will invoke your merge strategy.  If you *do* write your own merge strategy, though, you must make it do *everything*, and that's pretty difficult, as shown by the fact that there don't seem to be any third-party strategies available as Git add-ons.  In other words, the phrase *all you have to do* covers a multitude of sins, some of which are apparently pretty major. :-)

The *extended-options*—Git calls these *strategy options*, which seems like a poor name to me since `-s` is **the** strategy option—are just passed on to the strategy as options.  The standard strategy (or strategies, depending on whether you count resolve and/or subtree as separate strategies) allows `-X ours` and `-X theirs`, which aren't what you want in this case, but are worth mentioning, plus a whole host of additional `-X` options to tweak parameters in the algorithms.

For the most part, though, the standard strategy works by:

- finding the merge base (or bases, plural, for `-s recursive`) so that we have *one* commit to use as the merge base;
- comparing the merge base to `HEAD` and to the other commit, as if by two `git diff --find-rename` operations;
- combining the change-sets produced by the two `git diff`s.

If the recursive strategy finds two or more merge bases, it merges them as if by `git merge -s recursive`, one pair of commits at a time, committing each result.  Each such commit is temporary and has no branch name.  It does have a raw hash ID—*every* commit does, so this temporary commit does too—and the final merge result commit hash ID is the merge base commit.  Mostly, though, we end up with `-s recursive` finding some existing (single) merge base, so that commit is the one used as the merge base.  If the resolve strategy finds two or more merge bases, it picks one at what might as well be random.  (It's not actually random but it is whatever comes out of the base-finding algorithm first, and the order isn't specified and the base-finding algorithm might change in the future.)

So: at this point we have three commits:

- the merge base;
- the current commit, which is always `HEAD`, as `--ours`; and
- the commit you specified on the command line, as `--theirs`.

Some set of files exist in the base.  Those files are paired up with some set of files in `--ours`, according to the rename finding algorithm.  Any files that remain unpaired—that cannot be identified as "the same file" on left and right sides—are either added (nothing on left, new file on right) or deleted (nothing on right, left side file deleted).  Files whose name changed are renamed.  Files that have been paired-up and have their content modified are "modified" (and possibly also renamed).  The remaining paired-up files are unchanged at all.

The same thing happens with the base commit and the `--theirs` commit, producing lists of files that are modified and/or renamed, added, deleted, or unchanged at all.

Note that in principle, at this point, *all three* commits get yanked into the index.  (There's an optimization in which the index doesn't actually expand, if possible, but the outcome of this optimized approach is meant to match that of actually putting all three commits into the index.)  The way this works is that each entry in the index has a *staging slot number*.  So a file can occupy staging slots 1 (merge base), 2 (`--ours`), and 3 (`--theirs`) simultaneously.  Those are three copies of the file—or three blob references, to be precise—all of which use the same *file name* in the index.

Index staging slot zero is used for *resolved* files.  In this case there is no merge conflict for this file.

The next step is the *high level* merge operation: files that are renamed, must be renamed from the base to the final commit.  If both sides renamed a file, we have a rename/rename conflict.  Git declares a conflict for these files and picks one of the two new names as the target name to use in the work-tree.  Inside the *index*, however, the original name in the merge base occupies slot 1 for the base-commit name, the new name in `--ours` occupies slot 2 for the ours-commit name, and the new name in `--theirs` occupies slot 3 for the theirs-commit name.  It's just the fact that the work-tree file has to have *some* name that makes Git pick one (and I think Git uses the `--ours` name here, but I'd have to experiment to be sure).

If one side added a file named *F* and the other didn't, there's no conflict, but if both sides added a file named *F*, there is an add/add conflict on file *F*.

If one side removed a file, and the other side modified and/or renamed the file, there is a modify/delete or rename/delete conflict on that file.

In all of these high level conflict cases, all three files remain in the index, under their various names.  The work-tree file may or may not have some merge conflicts laid out in it as well, if there's a low-level conflict too.  But by this point all high level conflicts are recorded in the index and declared as conflicts, which will make the merge stop and get help; the file will not be resolved in the index.  **Note: this is all under the control of the merge strategy.**

Now that high-level conflicts are handled, we move on to whether there are low-level conflicts:

- If neither side modified a file—if it has the same hash in all three index slots—then there's no problem here.  The file can be moved to slot zero, using the hash ID from any of the three staging slots (as long as there are no high level conflicts of course).
- If one side of the merge modified a file, but the other side didn't, then there's no problem.  The file can be moved from whichever staging slot holds the *modified* file, to staging slot zero.  That is, file *F* has three hashes in the three slots.  Whichever one *matches* the slot-1 hash, we discard that one and take the *other* one as the merge result.  This goes to slot zero and the other three slots are erased (again only if there are no high level conflicts).  The work-tree file gets replaced with the retained index copy.
- For the last case, in which all three input files differ, we (finally!) invoke the actual low-level merge driver.

#### The low level merge driver is responsible for doing the actual merging

This is where your goal comes into view.  The default low level merge driver is the line-at-a-time one that produces the merge conflicts you've seen.  This program is built in to the strategy, but is available as a callable program as well, using `git merge-file`.  It takes three input file names, merges them as well as it can on its own, writes the result back to one of the three file names, and exits with a zero status if it thinks it merged the three files correctly, or nonzero if it left some conflict markers in the work-tree copy.

When the merge strategy invokes this low level merge driver, if the merge driver exits zero, the merge strategy copies the resulting file into index slot zero and erases slots 1–3 to mark the file resolved.  You never see a conflict here.  When it exits nonzero, though, the work-tree file *isn't* the correct result.  The three inputs remain in the index, in slots 1–3, and the merge will eventually stop with a conflict.  (Of course the strategy goes on to the remaining unmerged files first.)

If you set a *merge driver*, Git will run *your* command instead of using its built in equivalent of `git merge-file`.  Your driver should exit zero or nonzero as usual, and regardless of how it exits, should put its best effort at actually merging the three files into the work-tree.  You can achieve this however you like: the entire process is up to you.

So, if you want a fancier merge driver that can understand the programming language involved, or uses a word oriented diff instead of line diff, write one!  It's just a [small matter of programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_matter_of_programming).

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things I've discovered that can potentially make the merge job easier/better/more automatic.  None of these will solve the particular problem you're having, though:

1. When using git's “recursive” merge strategy (what you get by default when merging a single branch), you can pass `-Xpatience -Xdiff-algorithm=patience`, which are supposed to make it try harder to avoid conflicts.
2. [git subline-merge](https://github.com/paulaltin/git-subline-merge) is a wonderful little tool that merges at a finer granularity than per-line.
3. When you have widely divergent change histories [git imerge](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge) breaks conflicts into their logical parts, so you can deal with them one at a time, and may even be able to avoid some conflicts altogether by choosing a better path through the merge lattice.  Takes a while but is worth it when things get difficult.  It's especially good when the two histories are all working states because you can test the intermediate merge points.

Comment: There is also a `histogram` algorithm that is apparently a faster update to `patience`. I presume `-Xhistogram -Xdiff-algorithm=histogram` works though I haven't tested it.

Comment: It worked like a charm for me in xml files, resolving conflicts caused by moved blocks and different types of alignment (spaces x tab), all them mixed together.

Answer (score 1):

[MergeResolver](https://mergeresolver.github.io/) is an experimental GitHub app that suggests resolutions to merge conflicts in JavaScript files. When it detects a merge conflict, it first tries to conduct the merge on the level of abstract syntax trees. If that fails, it tries to use a merge conflict resolution strategy that passes the repo's test suite.

Or at least, that's what's claimed. I haven't tried it personally, and there doesn't seem to be any reviews of it.

In any case, there should be a lot of room for innovation in merge conflict resolution.

Answer (score -2):

Git's conflict presentations are already quite smart (I am not saying that the limit of smartness is reached), but you are expecting a mind-reading machine.

You start with a file that has this content:

```
X
...
```

modify one side into

```
Z
...
```

and the other side into

```
A
B
C
X
...
```

Note that empty lines are in no way special. Now you are expecting that the new line `Z` on one side matches the new line `D` on the other side, that line `C` of the other side *must* be in  the end result (your empty line), and  that new lines `A` and `B` are new?

How should Git guess that `Z` should be matched up with `X` and not with `A`, `B`, or `C`?

Quite a far stretched wish, isn't it?

Comment: You (and the current diff algorithm) are making the assumption that lines are either exactly equal, or that they are completely different. That clearly isn't the case - the edit distance between `async loadDirectory ...` and `loadDirectory ...` is lower than other line differences. Also I think your example is wrong - `A B C D ...` should be `A B C X ...`.

Comment: And even without line-level edit distances, it should be able to work out "Hmmm, in one branch `A B C` was inserted before `X`, but in the other branch `X` was modified to be `Z`, so I should probably show the diff as `A B C` inserted before `Z`.